# Can you right align a collection view?

Tags: cocoa

Normally the views in a collection view are left aligned, but this doesn't always look great, is it possible to right align or centre them?

e.g

```
|view1 view2 view3|
|            view4|
```

or

```
|view1 view2 view3|
|      view4      |
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I've reached the same conclusion, the documentation for collection views isn't that detailed but I can not find even a hint anywhere else. So I will use another method.